# Generate mesh at run time

Tags: python, mesh, game-engine

Is it possible to generate mesh at runtime in blender game engine? That is, is it possible for blender to generate meshes using python code when the game runs?

I really would like to know if this is possible, as my final year project requires use of this.

Comment: accordinto the [DOCs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bge.types.KX_MeshProxy.html?highlight=getvertex#bge.types.KX_MeshProxy) : `You can only change the vertex properties of a mesh object, not the mesh topology`  **you can't**

Comment: Now, I know that BGE does not allow runtime generation of meshes.
So if not at runtime, is it possible to generate these meshes through python script, just before a game starts? I am looking for something like a preloader that generates all mesh before a game level begins. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can : )  there are many examples see this [DOC page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Three_ways_to_create_objects) also you can find others by goggling if you hit another problem just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the page you mentioned speaks only of using python script to generate meshes in blender. It doesn't solve my question of whether it is possible to develop a preloader that would generate a mesh before a game runs.

Comment: I don't know about that ,  you can edit the question to get attention ( there are more experienced bge users here )

Answer (score 3):

The comment by Chebhou is almost correct... One thing that may not be clear, is that you can import bpy into bge scripts (many sources say this is not something you should do, but I have experienced no harm in using it during development, however, you can only use it in Blender - it will not work when you build/compile your final game). Thusly you can use the examples on the wiki page they linked to get started in generating meshes procedurally *for* your game, *within* Blender *during* development.

Unfortunately, there appears to be no way currently (as of version 2.78a) to construct a mesh from scratch during runtime of your game.

A couple of potentially useful rabbit holes, to show there may still be hope (will update this answer as/when I discover more):

- Generate, or "hack" a .blend file with your mesh data, and feed it to the dynamic loading system. This is all open source, so the specification should be readily available (or possible to glean from the source code).
- Alternative builds of Blender, which rumor suggests some are available with this functionality out of the box
- Modify Blender yourself...again: open source!
- Here is a nice thread about using BGL in BGE: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?301350-BGL-in-Blender-Game-Engine **this appears to be the most promising approach** and here is thoe documentation for BGL: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_60_4/bgl.html